# One recaptcha for multiple forms

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, recaptcha

I have multiple forms on one page and I want to protect using invisible reCaptcha v2.

My question is can I use one `<ReCAPTCHA />` to secure all the forms? or should I use one `<ReCAPTCHA />` for every form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one  outside of the forms and call it using reference on every submit.

don't forget to reset the captcha on every submit